# Trying to auto fill with VB for a really large spreadsheet >300,000 rows

Tags: excel, autofill, vba

In column A, I'm trying to duplicate the cell value in for the next 61 rows.  Below is my attempt, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I guess I'm not sure how to duplicate the cell values.    Thanks for any suggestions, as I would like to automate this since the spreadsheet has over 300,000 rows.

```vb
Sub AnotherAttempt()
'
' AnotherAttempt Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    iLoop = 2000
    For i = 1 To iLoop
            j = i - 1
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A4652 + 62*j:A4652 + 62*i - 1")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear for me what's the idea here, but for sure one thing is wrong... the way you're using j and i values. It should be like this:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & 4652 + 62*j & ":A" & 4652 + 62*i - 1)
```

The maths should be done out of the string.